# How to install a Python module to the non-default Python

Tags: python

I need to install mysql.connector to python3 but as python 2.7 is the default, it'll go there. How can I specify what python I want the module to be installed into? (I'm using mysql.connector.deb package)

Comment: I just done it downloading the source code and installing it according to mysql instructions using sudo python3 setup install

Answer (score 1):

while loading the module if you give python it will give you python 2.7. If you'd like to access python3 then simply type as python3 in your terminal.

```
frank@FRANK-NATHE:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:53:58) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

[1]+  Stopped                 python
frank@FRANK-NATHE:~$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 19:53:57) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

What I am trying to say is , use `python3` while installing the module. then it will go for `python3`.

To install the module for python 3 , do as

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks man. Yes, I downloaded the source and installed with python setup.py install, as the .deb package won't allow me to select the python version.

Comment: No what I am saying is , do as python3 setup.py install